# Add a card to Apple Wallet

Tags: ios, wallet, passkit

I am working on a mobile banking app and just want to add a card to Apple Wallet.
Here is my code:

```
Card *card = ...;
BOOL mayAddCard = [PKAddPaymentPassViewController canAddPaymentPass];

if(mayAddCard) {
    PKAddPaymentPassRequestConfiguration *addRequest = [[PKAddPaymentPassRequestConfiguration alloc] initWithEncryptionScheme:PKEncryptionSchemeECC_V2];
    addRequest.cardholderName = ...;
    addRequest.primaryAccountSuffix = ...;
    addRequest.localizedDescription = ...;
    addRequest.paymentNetwork = ...;

    PKAddPaymentPassViewController *vc = [[PKAddPaymentPassViewController alloc] initWithRequestConfiguration:addRequest delegate:self];

    if(vc) {
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

And I stuck here:

```
BOOL mayAddCard = [PKAddPaymentPassViewController canAddPaymentPass];
// mayAddCard == NO
```

First of all, I am running on simulator and iPhone 6s (iOS 11), developer builds. I already have merchant ID and Apple Pay Payment Processing certificate and Apple Pay Payment Processing and Wallet enabled in Developer account. I do not have that Apple private entitlement in my Provisioning Profile, though.

What should I do to get further?

Mainly, is it possible to test the addition to the Wallet on a test builds (without uploading to AppStore/TestFlight) at all?

Comment: HIii @ Andrey Solovyov. Did you add cards to wallet from your app? For that is necessary to have sandbox testing account?. please give idea about the how to add card to wallet from our app

Comment: Here is an amazing step by step document on how you can add card to Apple Wallet. https://medium.com/p/eae2458617bc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that it is completely impossible.

According to In-App Provisioning Getting Started Guide:

XII. Testing Prior to Release on the App Store

***Testing will occur through the use of the production environments. The iOS app will be distributed for testing purposes via the production App Store after the necessary approvals.*** A few points to note:

- The issuer must also provide the Adam ID, the numeric Apple ID of the application, to apple-pay-provisioning@apple.com prior to testing.
- The distribution of the app for testing purposes must be through the use of Promo Codes. Please look here for more information on the use of Promo Codes for limiting the distribution of an app via the App Store.
- Be sure to select “Manual Release” when submitting your app for App
  Review, otherwise you may inadvertently release the test app to the
  general public.
- Once testing is complete, the app can be made available for public
  download by selecting “Release This Version” within iTunes Connect.
  In case changes have been made to the app after inclusion on the App
  Store for testing, you will need to “Cancel This Release” within
  iTunes Connect. You can then re-submit your corrected app to the App
  Store for approval. Please click here for additional information on
  this part of the process.

  ***Please note that Test Flight can not currently be used to distribute apps for In-App Provisioning testing.***

Answer (score 2):

You can still push provision a card to apple wallet without using appstore or testflight. You have to hit apple's sandbox(QA) environment. For that you can request apple to give the profiles to change your device wallet to sandbox. Then you can push provision your test cards to wallet(sanbox).

Comment: I changed my Wallet to Sandbox, can you elaborate me how to Add a test card using the Sandbox environment form my app. I got the sandbox test vector from apple.

Comment: Should I use a real device, or simulator will be enough?

Comment: I think you can't use simulator here. Because the sandbox mode is enabled for the device only.

Comment: Balu, how did you change your wallet to be Sandbox?

Comment: What should be implementation for PKAddPaymentPassViewControllerDelegate methods?

Comment: Hi @RajeshRajendranPillai can you please give some insight on how to convert my device wallet to sandbox.?

Comment: @GauravBorole Have you figured out the answer to your question above where you asked "What should be implementation for PKAddPaymentPassViewControllerDelegate methods?"?